# How do I put some formatted text into the Clipboard?

Tags: delphi, text, clipboard

I'm writing a unit test for a "Text Scrubber" utility that will remove any formatting, etc. from the text on the clipboard.

For example, if you copy some text from a Word document or a web page with tons of formatting, you may want to paste it into another Word DOC as normal, plain old text.

To write a unit test for this, I need, of course, to write code that actually puts some formatted text into the clipboard.

So my question is -- how do I do that in Delphi code?

Comment: Does googling "delphi copy to clipboard" help? I see a few articles written about doing just this. Is there something specific that makes those articles unhelpful?

Comment: Yeah, they don't tell you how to put something in that is formatted or what that format should be.  For instance, this didn't really help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649016%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: You do know that Word and most applications also put formatted text on the clipboard in both formatted and also plain text.  When pasting you can choose which format you want by using the "Paste Special" command.
You may have other reasons for writing this program but if you are really just going from a word doc to another word doc everything is built in to strip out the formatting.

Comment: Mark -- yeah I know that.  What I need is a programmatical way to do that so I can test it in a unit test.

Comment: How awesome would it be if the Delphi IDE would put code in 2 formats on the clipboard, so that code that is copied and pasted in e-mails or word-documents has proper highlighting instead of plain text?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example on how to copy to the clipboard in html format:
http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1391

I've modified the code slightly so that it works in Delphi 2009.

```
//  If you've ever tried sticking html into the clipboard using the usual CF_TEXT
//  format then you might have been disappointed to discover that wysiwyg html
//  editors paste your offering as if it were just text,
//  rather than recognising it as html. For that you need the CF_HTML format.
//  CF_HTML is entirely text format and uses the transformation format UTF-8.
//  It includes a description, a context, and within the context, the fragment.
//
//  As you may know one can place multiple items of data onto the clipboard for
//  a single clipboard entry, which means that the same data can be pasted in a
//  variety of different formats in order to cope with target
//  applications of varying sophistocation.
//
//  The following example shows how to stick CF_TEXT (and CF_HTML)
//  into the clipboard.

function FormatHTMLClipboardHeader(HTMLText: string): string;
const
  CrLf = #13#10;
begin
  Result := 'Version:0.9' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'StartHTML:-1' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'EndHTML:-1' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'StartFragment:000081' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'EndFragment:°°°°°°' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + HTMLText + CrLf;
  Result := StringReplace(Result, '°°°°°°', Format('%.6d', [Length(Result)]), []);
end;

//The second parameter is optional and is put into the clipboard as CF_HTML.
//Function can be used standalone or in conjunction with the VCL clipboard so long as
//you use the USEVCLCLIPBOARD conditional define
//($define USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
//(and clipboard.open, clipboard.close).
//Code from http://www.lorriman.com
procedure CopyHTMLToClipBoard(const str: AnsiString; const htmlStr: AnsiString = '');
var
  gMem: HGLOBAL;
  lp: PChar;
  Strings: array[0..1] of AnsiString;
  Formats: array[0..1] of UINT;
  i: Integer;
begin
  gMem := 0;
  {$IFNDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
  Win32Check(OpenClipBoard(0));
  {$ENDIF}
  try
    //most descriptive first as per api docs
    Strings[0] := FormatHTMLClipboardHeader(htmlStr);
    Strings[1] := str;
    Formats[0] := RegisterClipboardFormat('HTML Format');
    Formats[1] := CF_TEXT;
    {$IFNDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
    Win32Check(EmptyClipBoard);
    {$ENDIF}
    for i := 0 to High(Strings) do
    begin
      if Strings[i] = '' then Continue;
      //an extra "1" for the null terminator
      gMem := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE + GMEM_MOVEABLE, Length(Strings[i]) + 1);
      {Succeeded, now read the stream contents into the memory the pointer points at}
      try
        Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
        lp := GlobalLock(gMem);
        Win32Check(lp <> nil);
        CopyMemory(lp, PChar(Strings[i]), Length(Strings[i]) + 1);
      finally
        GlobalUnlock(gMem);
      end;
      Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
      SetClipboardData(Formats[i], gMEm);
      Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
      gmem := 0;
    end;
  finally
    {$IFNDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
    Win32Check(CloseClipBoard);
    {$ENDIF}
  end;
end;

// Example:

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CopyHTMLToClipBoard('Hello world', 'Hello <b>world</b>');
end;
```

If you paste this in MS Word, you'll see this:

> Hello **world**

Comment: `CopyMemory(lp, PChar(Strings[i])` - PAnsiChar

Comment: `Strings[0] := FormatHTMLClipboardHeader(htmlStr);` -> `Strings[0] := UTF8ENCODE( FormatHTMLClipboardHeader(htmlStr) );` only UTF-8 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917.aspx

Answer (score 10):

In [DSiWin32](http://gp.17slon.com/gp/dsiwin32.htm) we have:

```
var
  GCF_HTML: UINT;

{:Checks if HTML format is stored on the clipboard.
  @since   2008-04-29
  @author  gabr
}
function DSiIsHtmlFormatOnClipboard: boolean;
begin
  Result := IsClipboardFormatAvailable(GCF_HTML);
end; { DSiIsHtmlFormatOnClipboard }

{:Retrieves HTML format from the clipboard. If there is no HTML format on the clipboard,
  function returns empty string.
  @since   2008-04-29
  @author  MP002, gabr
}
function DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard: string;
var
  hClipData       : THandle;
  idxEndFragment  : integer;
  idxStartFragment: integer;
  pClipData       : PChar;
begin
  Result := '';
  if DSiIsHtmlFormatOnClipboard then begin
    Win32Check(OpenClipboard(0));
    try
      hClipData := GetClipboardData(GCF_HTML);
      if hClipData <> 0 then begin
        pClipData := GlobalLock(hClipData);
        Win32Check(assigned(pClipData));
        try
          idxStartFragment := Pos('<!--StartFragment-->', pClipData); // len = 20
          idxEndFragment := Pos('<!--EndFragment-->', pClipData);
          if (idxStartFragment >= 0) and (idxEndFragment >= idxStartFragment) then
            Result := Copy(pClipData, idxStartFragment + 20, idxEndFragment - idxStartFragment - 20);
        finally GlobalUnlock(hClipData); end;
      end;
    finally Win32Check(CloseClipboard); end;
  end;
end; { DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard }

{:Copies HTML (and, optionally, text) format to the clipboard.
  @since   2008-04-29
  @author  MP002, gabr
}
procedure DSiCopyHtmlFormatToClipboard(const sHtml, sText: string);

  function MakeFragment(const sHtml: string): string;
  const
    CVersion       = 'Version:1.0'#13#10;
    CStartHTML     = 'StartHTML:';
    CEndHTML       = 'EndHTML:';
    CStartFragment = 'StartFragment:';
    CEndFragment   = 'EndFragment:';
    CHTMLIntro     = '<sHtml><head><title>HTML clipboard</title></head><body><!--StartFragment-->';
    CHTMLExtro     = '<!--EndFragment--></body></sHtml>';
    CNumberLengthAndCR = 10;
    CDescriptionLength = // Let the compiler determine the description length.
      Length(CVersion) + Length(CStartHTML) + Length(CEndHTML) +
      Length(CStartFragment) + Length(CEndFragment) + 4*CNumberLengthAndCR;
  var
    description     : string;
    idxEndFragment  : integer;
    idxEndHtml      : integer;
    idxStartFragment: integer;
    idxStartHtml    : integer;
  begin
    // The sHtml clipboard format is defined by using byte positions in the entire block
    // where sHtml text and fragments start and end. These positions are written in a
    // description. Unfortunately the positions depend on the length of the description
    // but the description may change with varying positions. To solve this dilemma the
    // offsets are converted into fixed length strings which makes it possible to know
    // the description length in advance.
    idxStartHtml := CDescriptionLength;              // position 0 after the description
    idxStartFragment := idxStartHtml + Length(CHTMLIntro);
    idxEndFragment := idxStartFragment + Length(sHtml);
    idxEndHtml := idxEndFragment + Length(CHTMLExtro);
    description := CVersion +
      SysUtils.Format('%s%.8d', [CStartHTML, idxStartHtml]) + #13#10 +
      SysUtils.Format('%s%.8d', [CEndHTML, idxEndHtml]) + #13#10 +
      SysUtils.Format('%s%.8d', [CStartFragment, idxStartFragment]) + #13#10 +
      SysUtils.Format('%s%.8d', [CEndFragment, idxEndFragment]) + #13#10;
    Result := description + CHTMLIntro + sHtml + CHTMLExtro;
  end; { MakeFragment }

var
  clipFormats: array[0..1] of UINT;
  clipStrings: array[0..1] of string;
  hClipData  : HGLOBAL;
  iFormats   : integer;
  pClipData  : PChar;

begin { DSiCopyHtmlFormatToClipboard }
  Win32Check(OpenClipBoard(0));
  try
    //most descriptive first as per api docs
    clipStrings[0] := MakeFragment(sHtml);
    if sText = '' then
      clipStrings[1] := sHtml
    else
      clipStrings[1] := sText;
    clipFormats[0] := GCF_HTML;
    clipFormats[1] := CF_TEXT;
    Win32Check(EmptyClipBoard);
    for iFormats := 0 to High(clipStrings) do begin
      if clipStrings[iFormats] = '' then
        continue;
      hClipData := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE + GMEM_MOVEABLE, Length(clipStrings[iFormats]) + 1);
      Win32Check(hClipData <> 0);
      try
        pClipData := GlobalLock(hClipData);
        Win32Check(assigned(pClipData));
        try
          Move(PChar(clipStrings[iFormats])^, pClipData^, Length(clipStrings[iFormats]) + 1);
        finally GlobalUnlock(hClipData); end;
        Win32Check(SetClipboardData(clipFormats[iFormats], hClipData) <> 0);
        hClipData := 0;
      finally
        if hClipData <> 0 then
          GlobalFree(hClipData);
      end;
    end;
  finally Win32Check(CloseClipboard); end;
end; { DSiCopyHtmlFormatToClipboard }

initialization
  GCF_HTML := RegisterClipboardFormat('HTML Format');
```

EDIT: 
@Edelcom: In Delphi 7, DSiWin32 should define

```
  _STARTUPINFOW = record
    cb: DWORD;
    lpReserved: PWideChar;
    lpDesktop: PWideChar;
    lpTitle: PWideChar;
    dwX: DWORD;
    dwY: DWORD;
    dwXSize: DWORD;
    dwYSize: DWORD;
    dwXCountChars: DWORD;
    dwYCountChars: DWORD;
    dwFillAttribute: DWORD;
    dwFlags: DWORD;
    wShowWindow: Word;
    cbReserved2: Word;
    lpReserved2: PByte;
    hStdInput: THandle;
    hStdOutput: THandle;
    hStdError: THandle;
  end;
  TStartupInfoW = _STARTUPINFOW;
  PStartupInfoW = ^TStartupInfoW;
```

I'll put this in and release new version.

Comment: This code works better than accepted variant (I had problems with pasting into TRichView component with last one)

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing this code  - I was just looking for a copy html to clipboard function.

Comment: I copied the DSiWin32 unit from your site, but this doesn't compile (it complains about a TStartupInfoW type), I am running Delhpi 7. can I change this into TStartupInfo ?

Comment: +1. Q: in `DSiGetHtmlFormatFromClipboard`, shouldn't `pClipData` defined as `PAnsiChar` for Unicode versions of Delphi (since it's UTF8)?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer from Wouter was a good start, but doesn't handle unicode characters. I modified the example code to work with unicode (html and text data). Also fixed memory leak.

```
function FormatHTMLClipboardHeader(HTMLText: UTF8String): UTF8String;
const
  CrLf = #13#10;
begin
  Result := 'Version:0.9' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'StartHTML:-1' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'EndHTML:-1' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'StartFragment:000081' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'EndFragment:°°°°°°' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + HTMLText + CrLf;
  Result := UTF8String( StringReplace( string(Result), '°°°°°°', Format('%.6d', [Length(Result)]), []) );
end;


//The second parameter is optional and is put into the clipboard as CF_HTML.
procedure CopyHTMLToClipBoard(const str: String; const htmlStr: String = '');
var
  gMem    : HGLOBAL;
  lp      : Pointer;
  HString : UTF8String;
begin
  {$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
  Win32Check(OpenClipBoard(0));

  try
    Win32Check(EmptyClipBoard);

    if ( htmlStr <> '' ) then
    begin
      // convert to utf8 and add header, which windows html clipboard format requires
      HString := FormatHTMLClipboardHeader( UTF8String( htmlStr ) );

      //an extra "1" for the null terminator
      gMem := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE + GMEM_MOVEABLE, Length(HString) + 1);
      {Succeeded, now read the stream contents into the memory the pointer points at}
      try
        Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
        lp := GlobalLock(gMem);
        Win32Check(lp <> nil);
        CopyMemory(lp, Pointer( HString ), Length( HString ) + 1);
        Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
        SetClipboardData( RegisterClipboardFormat( 'HTML Format' ), gMem);
        Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
      finally
        GlobalUnlock(gMem);
        GlobalFree(gMem);
      end;
    end;

    // Now just place plain unicode text, double buffer size as it's utf16
    gMem := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE + GMEM_MOVEABLE, ( Length(str) + 1 ) * 2);
    {Succeeded, now read the stream contents into the memory the pointer points at}
    try
      Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
      lp := GlobalLock(gMem);
      Win32Check(lp <> nil);
      CopyMemory(lp, Pointer( str ), ( Length( str ) + 1 ) * 2);
      Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
      SetClipboardData( CF_UNICODETEXT, gMem);
      Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
    finally
      GlobalUnlock(gMem);
      GlobalFree(gMem);
    end;

  finally
    Win32Check(CloseClipBoard);
  end;
  {$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM ON}
end;
```

Comment: A note to anyone attempting this - if you use this code as is you will find that calls to retrieve the clipboard data may fail because of the call to globalfree, if you have problems try without it.